# Sql error in manage a select to search for sequential hexadecimal number with hole after post join filter

Tags: sql, select, left-join, informix

I want to insert a hexadecimal sequential number in `ad_code` `char(5)` field and handle / fill its holes.

In order to speed up the query from initial table `table1`

```
Column name          Type                                    Nulls
ad_code              char(5)                                 yes
ad_value             smallint                                yes
```

I have create a view:

```
create view v_table1 (vacr_ad_code) as select
ad_code
from table1 where (NVL(ad_code, ' ') != ' ');
```

then I have tried to use this query to obtain a new value or eventually an hole:

```
select HEX('0x'||NVL( l.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT + 1
from v_table1 as l
left outer join v_table1 as r on
HEX('0x'||NVL( l.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT + 1 =
HEX('0x'||NVL( r.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT
where
r.vacr_ad_code is null ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

but with the following values in the db

```
vacr_ad_code    
1
2
4
```

instead of obtain 3 and 5 as I expected, I have:

```
(expression) 
        2
        3
        5
```

Why the number 2 is present ? Where I'm wrong ?

Update: If I modify the query in this way:

```
select HEX('0x'||NVL( l.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT + 1,
HEX('0x'||NVL( r.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT
from v_table1 as l
left outer join v_table1 as r on
HEX('0x'||NVL( l.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT + 1 =
HEX('0x'||NVL( r.vacr_ad_code, '0'))::INT
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

I obtain:

```
(expression) (expression)  
        2     2
        3     null
        5     null
```

If I add filter: `where r.vacr_ad_code is null` I obtain

```
(expression) (expression)  
        2     null
        3     null
        5     null
```

It seems that the post join filter alter the result of outer join

Comment: @I use Informix

Answer (score 1):

First, why doesn't your view just do:

```
create view v_table1 (vacr_ad_code) as
    select ad_code
    from table1
    where ad_code is not null;
```

I don't see how this would improve the speed of any query.

If you want "next" numbers that don't exist, I would first try:

```
select cast(t.ad_code as int) + 1
from table1 t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where cast(t1.ad_code as int) = cast(t.ad_code as int) + 1
                 );
```

I would suggest that you store `ad_code` as a number, because that is how you are using the value.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried your query and it works, but I would like to know why it does not work that proposed by me

Comment: @famedoro . . . Probably has to do with the hex conversions.  Those look really suspect for what you want to do.

Comment: Same problem also without hex conversions